# wingpanel in elementary os [hera] become large after i apply icons

Tags: wingpanel

[image]
wingpanel icons problem.**strong text**

im having a problem when i try to apply flattery icons to my elementary os my wingpanel icons become so large i want to know if there is a tutorial how to make it small or i want to use elementary wingpanel icons.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no solution for this, because the icon set has larger icons. So eventually you can resize them one by one in Inkscape. Or ask the developer of this icon set to make smaller version for Elementary OS.

https://github.com/cbrnix/Flatery